# How to get the src url and a href html

Tags: java, html, regex, url, src

I've this piece of html code. I want to replace the link placeholders for the content mentioned in three separate attributes. This is what I've tried so far:

```
    String texto2 = "url(\"primeiro url\")\n" +
    "url('2 url')\n" +
    "href=\"1 href\"\n" +
    "src=\"1 src\"\n" +
    "src='2 src'\n" +
    "url('3 url')\n" +
    "\n" +
    ".camera_target_content .camera_link {\n" +
    "   background: url(../images/blank.gif);\n" +
    "   display: block;\n" +
    "   height: 100%;\n" +
    "   text-decoration: none;\n" +
    "}";

    String exp = "(?:href|src)=[\"'](.+)[\"']+|(?:url)\\([\"']*(.*)[\"']*\\)";
    // expressão para pegar os links do src e do href
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(exp);

    // preparando expressao
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto2); 


    // pegando urls e guardando na lista
    while(matcher.find()) {


    System.out.println(texto2.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));   
    }
```

So far, so good - It works with find just that I need to get the clean link, something like this:

```
  img/image.gif
```

and not:

```
 href = "img/image.gif"
```

src = "img/image.gif"
     url (img/image.gif)

I want to replace one placeholder using one variable; this is what I've tried so far:

```
        String texto2 = "url(\"primeiro url\")\n" +
    "url('2 url')\n" +
    "href=\"1 href\"\n" +
    "src=\"1 src\"\n" +
    "src='2 src'\n" +
    "url('3 url')\n" +
    "\n" +
    ".camera_target_content .camera_link {\n" +
    "   background: url(../images/blank.gif);\n" +
    "   display: block;\n" +
    "   height: 100%;\n" +
    "   text-decoration: none;\n" +
    "}";

    String exp = "(?:href|src)=[\"'](.+)[\"']+|(?:url)\\([\"']*(.*)[\"']*\\)";
    // expressão para pegar os links do src e do href
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(exp);

    // preparando expressao
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto2); 


    // pegando urls e guardando na lista
    while(matcher.find()) {


    String s = matcher.group(2);
    System.out.println(s);  


    }
```

It turns out that this version does not work. It grabs the url perfectly; can someone help me spot the problem?

Comment: *"I'm a html text and need to get him the links.."*  Use an HTML parser.  Otherwise face [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418556)..

Comment: where I find this html parser?

Comment: Search engine 'java html parse'..

Comment: This is more than perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/).  Parse the HTML string into a DOM and you can then use CSS selectors to pull out the values as you would with jQuery in JavaScript.  Note that this will only work if you're *actually* working with HTML; the string at the top of your example is not HTML.